# pandas df.apply() not working with html.unescape()

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to decode html characters within a pandas dataframe.
I don't know why but my apply function won't work.

```
# requirements
import html
import pandas as pd

# This code works fine.
df = df.apply(lambda x: x + "TESTSTRING")
print(df) # "TESTSTRING" is appended to all values.

# This code also works fine. html.unescape() is working well.
fn = lambda x: html.unescape(x)
str = "Someting wrong with <b>E&amp;S</b>"
print(fn(str)) # returns "Something wrong with <b>E&S</b>"

# However, the code below doesn't work. The "&amp;" within the values dont' get decoded.
df2 = df.apply(fn)
print(df2) # The html characters aren't decoded!
```

It's really frustrating that the apply function and html.unescape() is working well separately, but I don't know why they don't work when they are together.
I've also tried `axis=1`

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `html.unexcape()` seems unvectorized, i.e. it accepts only one single string.
In case Your df is not really large, using `applymap` should still be sufficiently fast:

```
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: html.unescape(x))
print(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm not familiar with the concept 'vectorized', but I'll google and figure it out.